# How can I use numpy to create a function that returns two-dimensional values from arrays of data?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

This question is about deriving a mathematical function that returns pairs of values based on arrays of data - two-dimensional values from two-dimensional values.

I have created [a Python library that drives a pen-plotter using cheap servo motors](https://brachiograph.art).

[image: Immanuel Kant by BrachioGraph]

From the x/y position of the pen, I obtain the required angles of the motors, and from that the pulse-widths that need to be fed to them.

These cheap motors are of course rather non-linear and the mechanical system as a whole exhibits hysteresis and distorting behaviours.

The library can calculate the required pulse-width values in different ways. One way is to determine some actual pulse-width/angle measurements for each servo, like so:

```
servo_angle_pws = [
    # angle, pulse-width
    [ 45, 1000],
    [ 60, 1200],
    [ 90, 1500],
    [120, 1800],
    [135, 2000],
]
```

and then [use numpy to create a function that fits the curve](https://github.com/evildmp/BrachioGraph/blob/0dd9f44cd0fa129de71874682ba776d89b080a92/plotter.py#L88-L92) described by those values:

```
servo_2_array = numpy.array(servo_2_angle_pws)
self.angles_to_pw = numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(servo_2_array[:, 0], servo_2_array[:, 1], 3))
```

Which would look like this:

[image: angles-to-pulsewidths curve]

Now I'd like to take another step, and find a function in a similar way that gives me me the relationship between x/y positions and pulse-widths rather than angles (this will provide greater accuracy, as it will take into account more real-world imperfections in the system). In this case though, I will have two pairs of values, like this:

```
# x/y positions, servo pulse-widths
((-8.0,  8.0),  (1900, 1413)),
((-8.0,  4.0),  (2208, 1605)),
(( 8.0,  4.0),  ( 977, 1622)),
((-0.0,  4.0),  (1759, 1999)),
(( 6.0, 13.0),  (1065, 1121)),
```

My question is: what do I need to do to get a function (I'll need two of them of course) that returns pulse-width values for a desired pair of x/y positions? For example:

```
pw1 = xy_to_pulsewidths1(x=-4, y=6.3)
pw2 = xy_to_pulsewidths2(x=-4, y=6.3)
```

I believe that I need to do a "multivariate regression" - but I am no mathematician so I don't know if that's right, and even if it is, I have not yet found anything in my researches in numpy and scipy that indicates what I would actually need to do in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to perform a multivariate regression, which is equivalent to solving a multivariate least-squares problem. Assuming your function is a 2D polynomial, you can use a combination of [`polyval2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d.html) and [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html):

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyval2d
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

x = np.array((-8.0,-8.0, 8.0, -0.0, 6.0))
y = np.array((8.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 13.0))
pulse_widths = np.array(((1900, 1413),(2208, 1605),(977, 1622),(1759, 1999),(1065, 1121)))

# we want to minimize the sum of the squares of the residuals
def residuals(coeffs, x, y, widths, poly_degree):
    return polyval2d(x, y, coeffs.reshape(-1, poly_degree+1)) - widths

# polynomial degree
degree = 3

# initial guess for the polynomial coefficients
x0 = np.ones((degree+1)**2)

# res1.x and res2.x contain your coefficients
res1 = least_squares(lambda coeffs: residuals(coeffs, x, y, pulse_widths[:, 0], degree), x0=x0)
res2 = least_squares(lambda coeffs: residuals(coeffs, x, y, pulse_widths[:, 1], degree), x0=x0)

# Evaluate the 2d Polynomial at (x,y)
def xy_to_pulswidth(x, y, coeffs):
    num_coeffs = int(np.sqrt(coeffs.size))
    return polyval2d(x, y, coeffs.reshape(-1, num_coeffs))

# Evaluate the function
pw1 = xy_to_pulswidth(-4, 6.3, res1.x)
pw2 = xy_to_pulswidth(-4, 6.3, res2.x)
```

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed answer. It does produce the kind of output I require. However, I need to find a way to improve its accuracy. I have to collect many data-points otherwise it can produce rather wild results. I will experiment with the parameters of least_squares() to try to refine it.

Comment: @DanieleProcida Good point. You indeed need enough data points in order to obtain a good fit. For a polynomial degree of 3, you should pass *at least* (3+1)**2 = 16 data points. The more, the better. As soon as you have enough data points, you could also try higher polynomial degrees for a more accurate fit.

Comment: It's really interesting to experiment with the parameters and data points. With 9 data points and `degree = 2`, I get an average error of 17; with 16 and 3 I get it down to 10. I tried adjusting other parameters. `method` makes little difference. I tried `bounds=([np.array((-8, 6)), np.array((4, 13))])` but get an "Inconsistent shapes between bounds and `x0`" error, not sure why.

Comment: Each array in `bounds` must match the size of `x0` or be a scalar. That being said, are you sure you really want to impose bound constraints on the independent variables (= your polynomial coefficients)?

Comment: That just shows how poor my understanding is of all this; I took "independent variables" to be the x/y values that I would be supplying to the functions.